# Dropping button click events until last reset event not working

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, frp, cyclejs, xstream-js

Using cycle.js and xstream, I would like to count button clicks and reset them.

I was planning to achieve this by counting all button clicks after the last reset. To do this I thought of dropping all button clicks until the last reset, and counting what's left.

However I'm left with 2 buttons that are not working

Any advice?

```
function main(sources: ISources): ISinks {
  const dom = sources.dom;
  const resetClick$ = dom.select("#resetButton")
    .events("click")
    .map(ev => 0)
    .startWith(0)

  const button1Click$ = dom.select("#button1")
    .events("click")
    .compose(dropUntil(resetClick$.last()))
    .map(ev => 1)
    .fold((acc, n) => acc + n, 0)
    .startWith(0)

  const button2Click$ = dom.select("#button2")
    .events("click")
    .compose(dropUntil(resetClick$.last()))
    .map(ev => 1)
    .fold((acc, n) => acc + n, 0)
    .startWith(0)

  const vtree$ = Stream.combine(button1Click$, button2Click$)
    .map(n =>
      div([
        input("#button1", { attrs: { type: "button", value: "Click Me!"}}),
        input("#button2", { attrs: { type: "button", value: "Click Me!"}}),
        input("#resetButton", { attrs: { type: "button", value: "Reset!"}}),
        p(["Clicks: " + n[0] + " + " + n[1]]),
        p(["Click total: " + (n[0] + n[1])])
      ])
    )

  const sinks: ISinks = {
    dom: vtree$
  };
  return sinks;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const resetClick$ = dom.select("#resetButton")
  .events("click")
  .map(ev => 0)

const button1Click$ = dom.select("#button2")
    .events("click")
    .map(ev => 1)

const button1WithReset$ = Stream.merge(button1Click, resetClick$)
  .fold((acc, n) => { 
      if (n == 0) return 0
      else return acc + n
  }, 0)
```

This should do the trick. You can then do the same thing for `button2Click`.

By merging `button1click$` and `resetClick$` we get a stream, that either emits `0` or `1`. And using fold, we can reset the counter everytime our merged stream emits `0`.